# How do I set a timeout for pip so I can download packages on and unreliable Internet connection?

Tags: pip

I'm on an Internet connection that isn't stable or consistent. It will drop out randomly and not reconnect for `x` period of time.

Is there any way to install something via `pip` and instruct `pip` to not timeout? I've tried setting `--default-timeout` like so:

```
pip install pycryptodome --default-timeout=10000000
```

The idea being that it doesn't timeout for `10000000` seconds, which is ample time for my Internet to recover. The problem is when I do this and my connection comes back on the install doesn't resume. It just hangs at where it stalled previously.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to download the packages directly from the pip repositories using curl:

```
curl -L -O -C - https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d3/12/148242213240aea19aceb944414f165f35c98963fd27e27dab961ed07ecf/pycryptodome-3.9.6-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
```

This allows me to continue the download if it fails. And then to install:

```
pip install pycryptodome-3.9.6-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
```